# How do you write a input for 3 measurements so you write them in all at once and not line by line?

Tags: python, string, input

I'm making a really simple program for required measurements (length, width, thickness) of a package and I know there is way to input the all three without writing them line by line.

```
Measure = float('Specify in mm measurements length,width,thickness:')
M1 = Measure.split(',,')

K = L+W+T

if float(M[0]) 100 <= x <= 600 and float( M[1]) x <= 100 and float(M[2]) x <= 90 and K <= 900:
    print('Allowed!')
else:
    print('Not allowed!')
```

I get it wrong and I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: If you want to add multiple comma seperated values you shouldn't try to convert this input to a float. Split the input with a single comma and convert the individual values afterwards. Condensed: `M1 = list(map(float, Measure.split(','))`

Comment: Your `if` statement with `float(M[0]) 100 <= x <= 600` doesn't make sense. There is no `x` in the code and the syntax is screwed. If converted the values in `M` to floating point values before you do the comparison it's a simple `100 <= M[0] <= 600`.

Comment: I strongly recommend: https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/

Comment: And you might want to read the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/).

Comment: @yeah i forgot to add I'm like 2 weeks in on my python programming course

Comment: `x` is not defined. what is this ?

Comment: Change this (M[0])  to (M1[0]) and M[1]) to M1[1]). And this too M[2] to M1[2]